# How can I permanently tell Quarkus to use Nexus registry?

Tags: quarkus, nexus

How can I tell Quarkus to not download images from quay.io, but from our local registry? We have configured our Nexus to be a cache/proxy for all images, since we also want to control what images are being used.

Comment: Which images do you mean? the one the Docker files or the one used by dev-services?

Comment: I mean the ones used while building: First, I use an image to build the native executable (ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image) and then I need a base image for my container (quarkus-micro-image in my Dockerfile).

Comment: Try modifying quarkus.container-image.registry and quarkus.native.builder-image properties.

Comment: Thanks! `quarkus.container-image.registry` is used to push the new image, which we do outside of Quarkus. And reading https://quarkus.io/guides/native-reference#configure-quarkus-properties , it seems that I need a fully qualified name there. There seems to be no place where I could change just the server name. So I'll still use `registry.mycompany.com/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3-java17` .